# using named function for onclick of dijit menu item

Tags: javascript, dojo

Im having problem calling an onClick function for a dijit menu item.  I keep getting that the function is undefined:

Here is code for the menu item:

```
...
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/DropDownMenu" id="fileMenu">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem" data-dojo-props="onClick:function(){SetPage('test');}">Watershed</div>
        </div>
```

and here is the function I'm trying to call:

```
function SetPage(pg){
alert(pg);
}
```

do I have to register the onclick event in code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a scoping issue. Even when a function is named, it should be available in the global scope to be able to make it work with declarative code.

For example, if you put that function inside a `require()` block, it will not work, since it is scoped to that function only (it's only visible from inside).

For example:

```js
require(["dijit/MenuItem", "dijit/DropDownMenu", "dojo/parser"], function() {
  function SetPage(pg) {
    alert(pg);
  };

  SetPage("test"); // This will work because it's in the same scope
});

SetPage("test"); // This will not work
```

The lower `SetPage()` call has another scope, so it can't see the function. To solve the issue, the function has to be defined on the global scope (which is `window` for web applications).

A possible solution would be:

```js
require(["dijit/DropDownMenu", "dijit/MenuItem", "dojo/parser"], function() {
  window.SetPage = function(pg) {
    alert(pg);  
  }; 
});
```

This will work, because you add it to the `window` object. You can see an example of this on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/30hdn4pj/).

Answer (score 2):

this is the issue because of scope as setpage is not in the scope of onclick function of menu you can call directly alert function inside this like below:

`<div data-dojo-type="dijit/DropDownMenu" id="fileMenu">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem" data-dojo-props="onClick:function(){alert('test';}">Watershed</div>
        </div>`

or you can do attach a event handler here:

`<div data-dojo-type="dijit/DropDownMenu" id="fileMenu">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem" data-dojo-props="onClick:_onClick">Watershed</div>
        </div>`

and in your javascript file

`_onClick:function(evt){this.SetPage(evt);},
 SetPage:function(evt){ alert(evt.target.innerHTML);}`